# Can anyone tell me why this is happening "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query"?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

Our server is running on client site from last one year, but last night suddenly the server stopped responding because of some SQL/Hibernate exception, but after restarting server everything started working again.

Here is our hibernate configurations(.hbm.xml):

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/emessenger</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">5</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
```

Here is the exception trace, (similar three exceptions has been thrown on that time, if you want i can show you those exceptions also):

```
    2014-02-05 02:18:47,116 ERROR [services.alert.AlertDB] [577]: Exception occured while fetching <alert_details> table for quikc message  
   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at services.alert.AlertDB.retrieveMessageDetails(AlertDB.java:568)
    at services.alert.Alert.getMessages(Alert.java:925)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query execution was interrupted
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2693)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2102)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2261)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 34 more
```

Would anyone tell me what's wrong here, should we need to upgrade to new hibernate? or some MySQL settings has to be changed? Or is it related to c3p0 configurations?

Edited to add the first exception after which everything started:

```
[2014-02-05 02:18:26,085] WARN com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource : com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1b5c22f -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, and the pool is still live: some other thread must have either interrupted the Thread attempting checkout! 
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:305)
    at global.SessionMgmtListerner.thinClientStatus(SessionMgmtListerner.java:223)
    at global.SessionMgmtListerner.sessionDestroyed(SessionMgmtListerner.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:708)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.processExpires(ManagerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Atanu? I'm hitting the same error that a thread interrupt within BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable() causes C3P0 to get into a bad state and stop responding to requests.

Comment: Sorry, but no. We just optimized the queries in our server so as to use less connections & increased the maximum number of connection allowed in hibernate.

Comment: I did actually! We were not setting timeouts for cleanup within C3P0 nor were we enforcing checking for stale connections. Here are the properties we had to set. (Sorry about all the edits; formatting here doesn't do what you'd expect): c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod, c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin, c3p0.maxIdleTime, c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, will try these out, can you suggest something to compare performance with the changed configurations?

Comment: This was more of an issue on our dev environments as they had much longer periods of inactivity when stale connections would occure. To balance that we set the maxIdle timeouts to an hour and only checked for stale connections on checkin, this solved the dev issues. In production the check in check didn't hold up queries as the helpers did it out of scope and didn't make checkout slower. An hour of inactivity is never seen with production traffic but the idle timeouts don't seem to add much over head so we've left them in just in case all our customer take a really long lunch at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old mysql driver, use

`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Sure, will do that if required, but may i know why? and how was it creating this problem?

Comment: @AtanuPal it seems that your query execution is stopped which is strange, try downloading the latest mysql driver jar and replace the driver class name

Comment: Problem is I can not replicate this again, since its working fine after restart of server, but if this happens again then m screwed. and only thing i can trace out the problem from is the exception logs.

Comment: Are you sure that it will not give problem after we upgrade the libraries?

Comment: @AtanuPal Its always best to use correct driver class, rather than deprecated ones.It may or may not fix your problem.

Comment: This Server is very old, so m sure that all the code are in Sync, but if anyone knows that this was a issue in old driver which has been fixed now, that might give me more confidence and exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

The nested exception suggests that something on the MySQL server-side has interrupted the query.  I suggest you check the MySQL logs, and the system log (on the database server) for clues as to the possible cause.

There is not enough evidence to say whether the root cause is in Hibernate, C3PO, MySQL or the JDBC driver.  Or something else.  Without knowing what the root cause, nobody can confidently suggest a fix.  (Or at least, nobody can do that with *justifiable* confidence.  IMO.)

Comment: You are right, Got the one which started everything, will this help?

Comment: No.  Not really.  All it says is that *something* interrupted the thread that is doing session expiry.  I think you are going to have to solve this problem by trial and error.  You ALSO need to look at the MySQL logs ...